# Redirect Url sub-domain to sub-directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect url. When someone type `xyz.example.com` then its redirected to `example.com/zyz`.
I have No sub-domain.
I am trying when someone enters exact string `xyz.example.com` then redirect to `example.com/xyz`.
I am working on multi networking site.

```
xyz.example.com
```

This is not existing Domain .

```
example.com/xyz
```

This is multi-networking site url no sub-domain existing for this

Comment: If you do not own the subdomain, you can't redirect the subdomain.

Comment: So you don't have the subdomain `xyz.example.com` but want a redirect to your page? That's not possible.

Comment: LLJ97@it's any thing something like that. if someone type xyz.example.com . Then get get url string from  from url,Then Match first string from url and then redirect on  other url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to configure an apache virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/subdomainFolder"
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

In the other hand if you have a wildcard `*    IN    A    192.0.2.1` to map all subdomains to your primary domain ip. You may:

```
<?php
   $hotsname = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
   $arr = explode('.',$hostname);
   $url='http://example.com/';
   if(count($arr)>2){
      // we have a subdomain

      // redirect xyz only.
      if($arr[0] == "xyz"){
          header("location:" $url. $arr[0]);
          exit();
      }
   }

   // Continue normal operation, no redirect.

?>
```

[Apache VirtualHost Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Vidal@  after explode this  $arr = explode('.',$hostname);, can we use strop for condition ,If xyz string  in $hostname then only redirect

Comment: the example will redirect all subdmoains to their folder as you requested. ex. someSub.domain.com -> domain.com/someSub , you can do more if/else of case if you want to only redirect an specific sub-domain.

Comment: Vidal @but I have to match string.. If you have any idea Then Can you update this answer.I know we are on right path